# Double contexts inEntity Framework 6 makes calls slow?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Is there a general reason my database calls are slower when using two contexts?

When it was one database with one context the db call took less than 1 second. After moving some large tables to their own database and adding a second context the same call (to the new db) takes about 46 seconds.

Both databases are on the same MS SQL-server (2019 developer edition).

Comment: All those changes and you want to blame Entity Framework? Have you reindexed the database after moving around that much data?

Comment: Yes, I have. I even made a non clustered index for the question which makes it run on less than a second when I run it in MSSM.

Comment: Because they escalate to a distributed transaction? Although the increase should not be that drastic.

Comment: @GSerg thnak you I'll look in to that.

Comment: So what had happened was when I copied the data I used Select * into new_table  from  old_table. This creates a new table but not the PK for example. After creating the new table with the PK index and then copying the data everything started working better.